# My screen is not working

Tags: pi-3

I have a Pi 3 and I have just recently ordered a touch screen for it, I put the screen on the GUI prong things and then plugged it in with a Raspbian micro SD card and the screen turned on and just stayed white. Help? MY screen is Stutu 3.5" Touch Screen for Raspberry Pi 3 and the version of Raspbian is Raspberry Pi 16GB Preloaded (NOOBS) SD Card, Pre-installed, Class 10 - Raspberry Pi Recovery System

Comment: We need a more informations to help you. Can you give us the name of this screen, or the link where you bought it ?

Comment: Which screen do you have? Did the version of Raspbian come with the screen or is it the stock Raspbian? Normally you need to install the driver to make the screen do more than turn on the backlight (the white screen). Did the screen come with instructions? Software? If not you would be wise to remember that the cheap cost is not always worth it. Paying more to get a part from someone like Adafruit.com is well worth it because they provide clear, updated documentation, customer support etc.

Comment: This may be what you are looking for http://www.waveshare.com/wiki/3.5inch_RPi_LCD_(A) assuming you have a 3.5in TFT.

Comment: BTW the GUI prong things are called GPIO pins (general purpose in out)

Comment: That's why we are here, we were all noobs once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the Amazon [product page](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B072HTDC4V) to install the driver (edited for readability):

1. Download the [Raspbian image](https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/) (2017-06-21-raspbian-jessie.zip)

   **Note:** this will not work with any system using noobs.
2. Download the 3.5 inch display [driver](http://www.waveshare.com/wiki/3.5inch_RPi_LCD_%20(A)) here
3. Download the Raspberry Pi [Win32DiskImager](http://www.waveshare.com/wiki/File:Win32DiskImager.zip) then get (Win32DiskImager.zip)
4. Write the Raspbian image to SD card, using Win32DiskImager
5. copy LCD-show-170309.tar.gz into the SD card root directory
6. In the SD card root directory create a new file called ssh
7. Plug SD card into Raspberry Pi 3, boot the Pi, and use SSH to remote control the Pi, then execute this command :tar xzvf /boot/LCD-show-*.tar.gz

You can also download a [disk image](http://www.waveshare.com/wiki/3.5inch_RPi_LCD_(A)) with the driver preinstalled (RPi-35inch-LCD-Raspbian-160728.7z). Simply burn the downloaded file to your SD card.

As this screen is using the waveshare driver their [installation instructions](http://www.waveshare.com/wiki/3.5inch_RPi_LCD_(A)) may be clearer, and provide some additional usage and troubleshooting information.